# Filter on group level in SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have an SQL procedure that I use in Reporting(SSRS). It populates the employee and then the projects the employee has worked on - for example:

```
Employee 1 -- DepartmentXYZ
  Project 1 -- $500 (amount from employees of all Departments) [This is listed as Employee 1 has time on it]
  Project 2 -- $1500 (amount from employees of all Departments) [This is listed as Employee 1 has time on it]
```

I need to incorporate a parameter in the SQL Procedure that filters the employees on the department basis but does not affect the project level data.

It can easily be handled on the report level but owing to large data rows, this crashes the reporting software. It needs to be handled on the SQL level.

Currently if I use the filter in WHERE clause it filters data at the Project level too.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you without a better explanation of your issue and / or your current code.

Answer (score 1):

So you want a list of all employees for a department and the projects they have worked on giving the total value worked on these projects by all employees?

As you haven't shown your table structures or SQL, I'll just make some up which will hopefully be illustrative enough.

```
SELECT D.DepartmentName, E.EmployeeName, P.ProjectName, 
  SUM(T.Amount) AS TotalAmount, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN T.EmployeeID = X.EmployeeID THEN T.Amount END) AS EmployeeAmount
FROM Department D
INNER JOIN Employee E ON E.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID and D.DepartmentID = @DepartmentID
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT EmployeeID, ProjectID
  FROM Time
  GROUP BY EmployeeID, ProjectID) X ON X.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN Project P ON P.ProjectID = X.ProjectID
INNER JOIN Time T ON T.ProjectID = P.ProjectID
GROUP BY D.DepartmentID, E.EmployeeID, P.ProjectID
ORDER BY BY D.DepartmentID, E.EmployeeID, P.ProjectID
```

So what we are doing is getting all the employees for the department specified by the `@DepartmentID` parameter and then using a subquery to find all the projects those employees worked on. Then we join to all those projects, get all the time entries regardless of who they were for and sum them. For bonus points we also calculate the employee's contribution to the project.

Comment: This exactly will help me in re-structuring my code. I will paste the table structure and FYI I am using SSRS 2005 for reports, obvious reasons.


FROM
   Transaction (has all the details like timeentry date,timeentryemployee[used as first group on report] etc..)
   LEFT  JOIN Project(this has project department/ProjectID used as second group) ON Key = transactionProject
   LEFT  JOIN Employee(has employee department) ON transKey = empKey

Can you please help me in restructuring the above structure.

Thanks, already!!

Comment: Can you please add to this question, I have added a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69772176/sql-server-procedure-filter-on-a-specific-group